# What am I doing wrong in this jQuery link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, widget

I am a complete newbie when it comes to jQuery, but I'm trying to run a simple accordion() code on my HTML page.

This is the link I've used, I included the compressed production jQuery 2.1.0

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetkomik2.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptkomik2.js"></script>
    <title>Komiktoneel</title>
</head>
```

The piece of code I'm trying to accordion() is a series of  tags with  tags in them, which contain paragraphs, like this:

```
<div id="content">
<h3>This is the first heading</h3>
<div><p>First paragraph</p></div>

<h3>This is the second heading</h3>
<div><p>Second paragraph</p></div>
</div>
```

scriptkomik2.js contains nothing other than the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#content").accordion();
})
```

Is there something wrong in my code or is the linking wrong?
Thank you

Comment: what's the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I think you're missing some directives. `.accordion();` is not native from jQuery library.

Comment: You have to add to head this:  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: The worst thing you are doing here is not using your console... ;)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

`Accordion` is a widget from **jQuery UI** and this library works on top of **jQuery**. So you need to add both js to your project.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) is missing. You have to add jQueryUI as well for accordian widget.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetkomik2.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptkomik2.js"></script>
    <title>Komiktoneel</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

.accordion isn't a valid jQuery method. I think you're looking for jquery UI: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Try implementing that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following script tag. Accordion is part of jQuery UI

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```